# Why does aptitude include Minesweeper?

Tags: aptitude

Any of the more observant of you will have noticed that aptitude(8) contains the game Minesweeper, accessable from the Actions menu.

Is there a particular reason or some history as to why this was introduced? Perhaps to keep sysadmins entertained whilst they waited for packages to install?!

[image]

Comment: Can't tell you *why*, but it seems like the feature was merged into `aptitude` at 2001-05-14 according to the `ChangeLog.SVN` in the repository. Maybe send a mail to [Daniel Burrows](http://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=dburrows@debian.org)?

Comment: does the option actually play minesweeper? It does appear that its open source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_%28video_game%29  I'm sure the answer is an enlightening as the reason someone wrote cowsay.